# Android Emulator couldn't start, 8.0

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

I'm using VS2017 Xamarin and I cannot launch the android emulator.
Error message: "Unable to load DLL 'DismApi': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I'm using Android 8.0, have SDK downloaded.
How can I fix that?

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: which Windows do you use? I have the file in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you‘re using Win 7 you can‘t use the emulator. The minimum system requirements are 64 bit version of Win 8.

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/cross-platform/system-requirements-for-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android?view=vs-2017)